# Ajax to send javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm trying to send a javascript string variable from a javascript plugin of a program running in tomcat, to a php file hosted on apache (httpd on centOS) on the same physical machine.

Trying to send it using ajax and POST, and storing it as a variable on the php file.

I'm new to php

php:

```
<?php

    if($_POST['zone']){
        $zone=($_POST['zone']);
        echo $zone;
    }
?>
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'urlofmyfile.php',//url of receiver file 
    data: {zone: zone}, //your data
    success: function(msg){console.log('Write succeeded' + msg);}, //callback when ajax request finishes
    dataType: 'jsonp' //text/json...
});
```

I initially got some errors about cross domain problems, then switch to jsonp as the dataType

Comment: What is the value of zone?  Can you provide the full error message please.

Comment: `<p>Hello World</p> plus value of $zone` -- which is returned by your php -- is not valid JSONP ... **see the `<` character in the result returned by your PHP?**

Comment: The value of zone is a string of lowercase letters and numbers something like f87ekheuf836hgh

Comment: the url is ipaddress/file.php  - when I load the url in the browser it works.

Comment: Thanks I got rid of the echo hello world and the error is gone,

Comment: But the variable in php does not appear to be being set or echoed out

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Even though they're on the same machine you need to understand [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: I feared as much :( thanks

Comment: Maybe moving your dataType above your success might do something.  And if you're getting cross domain problems, in your php add a header to allow access requests, like this header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

it might help to also send that header in your ajax call too.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, working using the answer below with the addition of header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  in the php file as bwalshy said. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $.post for this kind of request and use json output in PHP for better communication with JQuery. One more thing, you also need to check whether the value of zone is not empty or what!

### in PHP Code

```
<?php
$output = array('status'=>true,'message'=>'');
if(!empty($_POST['zone']) && $_POST['zone']){
    $zone=($_POST['zone']);
    $output['status'] = 'true';
    $output['message'] = $_POST['zone'];
}
else
{
    $output['status'] = 'false';
    $output['message'] = 'No value passed';
}
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($output);
```

This will help to check better operation of PHP script via javascript

### in Javascript

```
$.post(urlofmyfile.php,
{
 zone: zone
},
  {
  function(data,status){
    if(data['status']=='true'){
        //It's Done
    }
    else
    {
       //it's not done
    }
  }
}
);
```